# EVFILT_WRITE returning twice

Tags: c, freebsd, kqueue

I'm trying to send a buffer to my socket client when the file descriptor is available for writing.

**EV_SET** is set to: **EVFILT_WRITE, EV_ADD | EV_DISABLE  | EV_CLEAR**

then when changed to **EVFILT_WRITE, EV_ENABLE**  then **EVFILT_WRITE** get triggered once which is great!

but if i use the function **write** or **send** when i get **EVFILT_WRITE** like this:

```
if (e->filter == EVFILT_WRITE)
send(socket, buff, strlen(buff), 0);
```

then i get again another **EVFILT_WRITE** event. It seems like the send function trigger another EVFILT_WRITE event. is that expected behaviour?  I thought EVFILT_WRITE triggers only when the file descriptor is available for writing.

I searched for the issue, but it looks like nobody mention that. Can someone please confirm if that is expected behaviour and why?

Comment: Do you get an error from a second `send` or is that successful?

Comment: Hi there its successful

Comment: Seems to me that the file descriptor is still available for writing.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand it:

Since you used `EV_CLEAR`, the `kevent` facility starts to return **state transitions**, not the **current state**. So, whenever you touch the `socket` descriptor with `kevent()` or `send()` calls, you get an `EVFILT_WRITE` event back.

Another way to look at this:

When `send()` is called the descriptor becomes unavailable for writing for a moment and then again becomes available, which is why you get an event.

I'll try to loop in some knowledgeable people to this question.

Comment: I tried to call send() 10 times in a loop, but  it result in 2 EVFILT_WRITE...  according to what you said it should return 11 EVFILT_WRITE?

Comment: This is probably because consecutive `send()` calls get aggregated. Try waiting for a `EVFILT_WRITE` event before making the next `send()` call.